# sending query to sqlplus

Tags: sqlplus

I have a script file which sends query to sqlplus and sends the output to some other output file.
However, this output file contain some info from sqlplus - some kind of greeting.

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Jan 15 12:30:40 2013                         

Copyright (c) 1982  2011     Oracle.  All rights reserved.                  


Connected to:                           
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production                            
With the Partitioning    Real Application Clusters   Automatic Storage Management    OLAP               
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

is there some way to execute the script so that this greeting will not be as part of a file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sqlplus -s` option when you connect to the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
Execsqlstatement1="select
'ZZZ|'
||count(*) total
from table1"


$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus user/tneal01 << Eossql
    set lines 80
    set pages 50000
    set timing on
    spool /user/tneal01/SPOOL/output.`date +%Y-%m-%d`.tmp
    $Execsqlstatement1
    /
    spool off
    quit;
Eossql
```

Now if you don't want anything besides the result in the output file you can do something like this in your script:

```
grep 'ZZZ' $OutPutDir/$OutPutFile.$today.tmp|cut -d"|" -f2- >$OutPutDir/$OutPutFile.$today.txt
```

Here is a full example on why this works:

```
#!/bin/ksh

today=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
OutPutDir="/users/ttead01/SPOOL"
OutPutFile="output"

#add sql statements here

Execsqlstatement1="select
'ZZZ|'
||count(*) total
from users"


#adding connection details here

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus tead01/rangers $SQLPLUS -s / << Eossql
    set lines 80
    set pages 50000
    set timing on
    spool /users/ttead01/SPOOL/output.`date +%Y-%m-%d`.tmp
    $Execsqlstatement1;
    spool off
    quit;
Eossql

#check to make sure no ORA errors in the query

grep "ORA-" $OutPutDir/$OutPutFile.$today.tmp
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "LOG MESSAGE sql select failed"


 exit 1
fi

#Seach for ZZZ and cut out junk and send only result to a .txt file

grep 'ZZZ' $OutPutDir/$OutPutFile.$today.tmp|cut -d"|" -f2- >$OutPutDir/$OutPutFile.$today.txt

#Remove the .tmp file if .txt was created

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  /usr/bin/rm -f $OutPutDir/$OutPutFile.$today.tmp
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Now for the test:

bash-3.2$ test.sh

```
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.




SQL> set autocommit on;
SQL> rem set linesize 132;
SQL> define _editor = vi
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS';

Session altered.

SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8
TOTAL
--------------------------------------------
ZZZ|32

Elapsed: 00:00:00.17
```

Now let's look at the output .txt file:

```
bash-3.2$ cat output.2016-05-28.txt
32
bash-3.2$
```